# How to fix botched title edit?

Tags: support, mathjax, suggested-edits, titles, markdown-preview

I edited the title of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814726/int-0-infty-ln1x-sqrt32-1-x-sqrt3-2-1x2-ln-xdx-text) to remove the `\displaystyle` in the title, but, in the process, I deleted a brace.  As a result, it won't compile; but the edit has been accepted.  (As far as I could tell, the preview window shows only a preview of the body, not the title; is this correct?  Is there any way to see how the title will (or won't) render before attempting the edit?)

I can't insert the brace (it's too small an edit).  Would it be possible for a moderator to fix my goof?

Comment: The title of this particular question has been changed [a few times since your edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1814726/revisions)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, yes, I noticed, and it's a shame (because now it says nothing about the actual integral in question).  Thanks for fixing my edit.  For my future reference, is there any way to preview the title, as well as the body, of the post when editing?  (Maybe I just missed it.)

Comment: Nothing to thank me for - it was actually the OP who changed the title. As far as the preview of the title is concerned, I cannot think of anything better than copying the title into the body. Let's wait and see whether somebody posts an answer here with some more information.

Comment: BTW based on these older posts it seems that this is a problem only for [suggested edits](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/suggested-edits/info): [On question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/on-question-titles) and [Latex preview on question title?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20248/latex-preview-on-question-title) (Well, also when asking a question, but what you wrote here was mainly related to editing.)

Comment: If I'm in doubt about how it will render, I copy the title into the question and check it's fine. Then remove before submission.

Comment: @LSpice Better now?

Comment: @Did, yep, thanks!

Comment: I posted this on [meta.se]: [Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361217). (There is an older question which is a bit similar: [Please include the title in the question preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115247). But probably it is worth pointing out that this is a problem mainly on the sites which use MathJax.)